# Не работает css transition хотя я и не пользовался display none

Tags: css

Вот код

```
#catalogContainer .catalog {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s 1s ease;
  background: rgb(128,203,196);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(128,203,196,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 70%);
}
#catalogContainer .catalog:hover {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #80CBC4;
  background: rgb(128,203,196);
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(128,203,196,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 70%);
}
```

Доп инфо:
Данные которые должны анимироваться интегрированы и итерируются в js файле

Comment: Градиенты пока не поддерживают transition, проверьте обычное изменение фона

Answer (score 2):

Если невозможно пока анимировать параметры самого градиента напрямую, то можно попытаться имитировать нужный эффект, изменяя свойства влияющие на отображение.

Например, `background-position`:

```css
#catalogContainer .catalog {
  height: 70px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(128, 203, 196, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 35%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 65%, rgba(128, 203, 196, 1) 100%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#catalogContainer .catalog:hover {
  height: 140px;
  background-position: 100% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="catalogContainer">
  <div class="catalog">
    каталог
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно задействовать псевдоэлементы с разнонаправленными градиентами и показывать/скрывать нужный, изменяя их `opacity`. Такой подход наиболее близок к желаемому эффекту:

```css
#catalogContainer .catalog {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
#catalogContainer .catalog:hover {
  height: 140px;
}
#catalogContainer .catalog::before,
#catalogContainer .catalog::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(128, 203, 196, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 70%);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
#catalogContainer .catalog::after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(128, 203, 196, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 70%);
}
#catalogContainer .catalog:hover::after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="catalogContainer">
  <div class="catalog">
    каталог
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Кроме градиента при наведении меняется и высота, но оно тоже не плавно меняется

Comment: @KhasanAlimov: добавил. Всё меняется плавно.

Answer (score 1):

Я знаю как это сделать не при наведении и только с помощью анимации `@keyframes`

```css
@property --degCatalog {
  syntax: '<angle>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 90deg;
}

#catalogContainer .catalog {
  background: linear-gradient(var(--degCatalog), rgba(128,203,196,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 70%);;
  animation: animCatalogDeg 1s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes animCatalogDeg {
  0% {
    --degCatalog: 90deg;
  }
  100% {
    --degCatalog: -90deg;
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .catalog {
    height: 100vh;
  }

</style>

<div id="catalogContainer">
  <div class="catalog">
    каталог
  </div>
</div>
```

Но скорее всего, вы хотели не плавно менять градусы, а цвета:

```css
@property --leftColor {
  syntax: '<color>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: rgba(128,203,196,1);
}

@property --rightColor {
  syntax: '<color>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: rgba(128,203,196,1);
}

#catalogContainer .catalog {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--leftColor) 0%, var(--rightColor) 70%);;
  animation: animCatalogColor 1s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes animCatalogColor {
  0% {
    --leftColor: rgba(128,203,196,1);
    --rightColor: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  }
  100% {
    --leftColor: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    --rightColor: rgba(128,203,196,1);
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .catalog {
    height: 100vh;
  }

</style>

<div id="catalogContainer">
  <div class="catalog">
    каталог
  </div>
</div>
```